# sql developer hangs on startup - what can I do?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

At present I cannot run it (SQL Developer 4.1) because it hangs on "Restoring Editors" while starting. I suppose I've done it by exiting it before by killing sql developer process because it was hanged on fetching objects to Schema Browser so long...
Maybe I would clean some temporary files but can't find any.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basing on this thread https://community.oracle.com/thread/2564842 I've created own solution.

1. Extract installation of current version SQL Developer (**4.1.0.17.29**)
2. At "c:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\"
   I've changed directory name **system4.1.0.17.29** to ***system4.1.0.17.28.***
3. After running newly extracted SQL Developer (**4.1.0.17.29**) I was prompted to let copy configuration from version ***4.1.0.17.28*** to **4.1.0.17.29** ;)
4. Everything works great now. I suppose that running the same (broken) installation after decreasing version could also help.

Answer (score 20):

Deleting files from c:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\SQL History 
and c:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\System...
Really helped me to resolve the connection issues

Comment: this time cleaning SQL History was enough - thanks for tip

Comment: This solution is a bit extreme as removing "Roaming\SQL Developer\system.xx" will delete any customisation you made on Sql Dev.
Better only clear  "Sql History" and "Roaming\SQL Developer\system.xx\system_cache*" as mentioned below. This will keep your preferences.

Answer (score 18):

Remove folders c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system4.1.3.20.78\system_cache*.  SQLDeveloper will recreate it after launching.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: On macOS: `$ rm -fr ~/.sqldeveloper/systemXX.X.X.XXX.XXXX/system_cache*`

Comment: Thank you so much, @Panic ... for Linux this solved the issue as well :) ... The folder structure is a bit different, but still - deleting the `system_cache*` one(s) did the job :)

Comment: I'm using CentOS 7 and SQL Developer 20.4, and the rm -rf system_cache* worked for me too. I had to restart my machine though in order for sqldeveloper to work again.

Comment: On Windows you can abbreviate the path as "%APPDATA%\SQL Developer\{the rest stays the same, according to your SQL Developer version}"

Answer (score 6):

Just execute sqldeveloper as administrator. It works fine!

Comment: There is no way I would trust software from Oracle to run as administrator considering their history of software quality.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was because of windows compatibility issue. So I've selected my windows version and it's stop from randomly crash after startup  [image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case when i changed `Tools --> Preferences --> Environment -> Look and Feel` to `Windows` it is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Our setup:

- Windows 10
- Sqldeveloper Versions <= 20.4.0

We observed this problem as well. Even worse while working over a VPN connection. I followed a couple of hints with more or less no effect.

To move

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer
```

to a local directory by adding this line

```
AddVMOption -Dide.user.dir=c:\temp\sqldev-conf
```

in the \sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf file gave us some improvement, but the “IndexPreferencesTask” still got stuck several times on startup.

After some more hours on unsuccessful research, we moved back from JDK 11 to JDK 8.
This solved 99% of the problem. The “IndexPreferencesTask” still hangs on startup but for less than a second.

Sounds to me like a problem with JDK 11.

Answer (score 2):

Vague title; for anyone having IndexPreferencesTask problems:

Open the conf file...

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\<version>\product.conf
```

Add this line to the end of the file on a new line:

```
AddVMOption -DIndexedPreferencesCommand=false
```

As far as my research shows, it just indexes preferences, so the only negative outcome is it will take longer to search for preferences - which I personally never do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the History files from `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper`
2. Restart the PC

Answer (score 1):

```
Operating System: Windows 10
Oracle Sqldeveloper Ver: 17.4.0

The problem has been noticed sometime when any network security 
patch was installed on your machine. Looks like the patch impacts 
your cached data under your user profile folder.
As above Lakh, rtbf and others answered. Removing below folders 
will resolve the issue.

C:\Users\<userId>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\SqlHistory
C:\Users\<userId>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system17.4.0.355.2349

If any one find more approriate reason please feel free to 
disagree with my answer.
```

Comment: Does that mean I'll have to do this for every security patch?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was kind of weird. After battling to resolve this for 2 days, no luck. Suddenly, on my mac, I searched for sql developer, not sqldeveloper. It popped up a sqldeveloper application (not sure how that is different from what I have been trying to open ), clicked it and boom, it opened. My guess is that there is a copy of that app on my system that I should have been opening rather than trying to open the reinstalled app. Note: I reinstalled the app after it started misbehaving though.